# Error al conectar aplicacion android con servidores de firebase

Tags: firebase

Estoy tratando de conectar mi app a firebase y cuando llego al cuarto paso,(aqui esta en el link)
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/delete123-30fd2/overview

se queda cargando infinitamente,reviso la parte del Logcat y encuentro este error.

```
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.phenotype
```

llevo dias con este error porfavor podrian ayudarme.

Comment: Nosotros no podemos acceder a tu proyecto delete123-30fd2 porque no tenemos permisos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se refiere a un problema al tratar de usar el provider, en realidad se refiere a una [API de Google](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) , pueden ser dos causas que no este habilitada la API o que no se pueda obtener la dependencia.

Asegura tener en tu `build.gradle` dentro del bloque `repositories` lo siguiente

```
  repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
```

Ahora asegura que la API que deseas usar se encuentre habilitada en la consola

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]